# How to loop through JSON object (not array)?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The JSON data is in a format like:

```
"data": {
  "x-y": {
    "name": "x-y",
    "enabled": true,
  },
  "a-b": {
    "name": "a-b",
    "enabled": true,
  },
}
```

From a WebSocket client, I receive the data as a string. The number of key-value pairs inside "data" is not fixed - i.e. one time it might just return "x-y", and another it may return "x-y", "a-b", "foo-bar", etc.. and the possible names of the keys that might be received are not known.

From my brief and limited experience working with WebSockets and JSON, it seems that usually in a scenario like this the data would be contained in a array - something like this:

```
"data": [
  {
    "name": "x-y",
    "enabled": true,
  },
  {
    "name": "a-b",
    "enabled": true,
  },
]
```

In this second scenario I could just loop over the data - no problem. Is it possible to do something similar for data as in the first example? AFAICT [this is possible in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_object_loop), but couldn't find a similar solution in C#.

Comment: Well if its possible in javascript..... of course C# can do it, not only that, it will look good while doing it.

Comment: Deserialize to a `JObject`

Comment: Ahh it turns out it was they had it structured as `data: {data: {..` (two datas - nothing else either, just purely redundant!). JObject was also what I needed - got it working now, thanks!

Comment: Deserialize it into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. Each Dictionary represents an object the the collection. The `Keys` collection gives you the property names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways and variations of how to do this (not limited to the below)

**Given**

```
public class Stuff    {
   public string name { get; set; } 
   public bool enabled { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
   public Dictionary<string,Stuff> data { get; set; } 
}
```

**Examples**

```
var input = "{\"data\": {\r\n  \"x-y\": {\r\n    \"name\": \"x-y\",\r\n    \"enabled\": true,\r\n  },\r\n  \"a-b\": {\r\n    \"name\": \"a-b\",\r\n    \"enabled\": true,\r\n  },\r\n}}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(input);

Console.WriteLine("Attempt 1");
foreach (var item in result.data.Values)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.name} {item.enabled}");

// or

Console.WriteLine("Attempt 2");
var asd = JObject.Parse(input);

foreach (var item in asd["data"].Children().SelectMany(x => x))
   Console.WriteLine($"{item["name"]} {item["enabled"]}");
```

**Output**

```
Attempt 1
x-y True
a-b True
Attempt 2
x-y True
a-b True
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiW5rA)

Answer (score 1):

Here's documentation on parsing JSON into a C# Object. You mention not array, not sure if you were implying the JSON having objects and not arrays or you wanted in C# not as arrays.

[https://www.codementor.io/@andrewbuchan/how-to-parse-json-into-a-c-object-4ui1o0bx8](http://Here%27s%20documentation%20on%20parsing%20JSON%20into%20a%20C#%20Object.%20%20%20https://www.codementor.io/@andrewbuchan/how-to-parse-json-into-a-c-object-4ui1o0bx8)

Comment: I guess what I wrote didn't make sense, sorry about that. I misunderstood how it all worked. Thanks for giving me the hint there :).

Comment: No problem! haha